# Log4j PropertyConfigurator.configure() will not accept a string in eclipse

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a strange issue, probably something simple but I've been googling for 20 mins now with no resolution

I'm trying to use log4j in Eclipse. I downloaded the latest zip and added to my classpath. I have created the properties file by copying from a tutorial. The properties file is in the root folder of my project and is named "log4j.properties". The file contains

```
#define the console appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# now define the layout for the appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# now map our console appender as a root logger, means all log messages will go to this     appender
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, consoleAppender
```

My class is as follows, eclipse has the following error at the PropertyConfigurator.configure() line. 
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ""log4j.properties"", delete this token
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

However the api for log4j shows that propertyconfigurator should accept a string. Any suggestions?
 -

```
package org.dnsdojo.ryanhost.GA.MuPlusOne;

import java.util.Random;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;


public class Genome
{
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Genome.class);
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
byte[] genome;
Random rng = new Random();
String genomeString = "";

public Genome ( int stringLength, int motorSet )
{
    genome = new byte[ stringLength * 7 * motorSet]; // stringLength depends on how many bytes you wish to have. For the arpibot this is dependant on the number of sensor readings taken
    for (int i = 0; i < genome.length; i++)
    {
        genome[i] = (byte)rng.nextInt(2);
        genomeString += genome[i];
    }
    logger.debug(genomeString);     
}

public byte[] getGenome()
{
    return genome;
}

public byte[] mutate (float mutationStep)
{
    return genome;                                  //placeholder
}

}
```

Comment: You can't execute arbitrary code anywhere in your class! You need to put your method call in a `static{}` block, in a `{}` block or in some method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `PropertyConfigurator.configure` in the class block so the compiler is complaining. Move the statement (along with the other non-declarative statements) into a method or `static` initializer block.

Comment: Wow what a derp >.> In my defense I think I've been looking at this for too long! Thanks though

Comment: One question arises from this - once I fixed the code my logger is returning some strange line numbers. It is skipping some and duplicating others. Is this due to my properties file or maybe my code?

Comment: Hard to say. Check that your deployed code corresponds with that your current code, i.e. not running with old class versions. Not sure how many loggers you are using. Check out [additivity](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-additivity-what-and-why/)...

Comment: Thanks, I'll open a different question on this. I tried adding log4j.additivity.consoleAppender = false with no change

Comment: @Reimeus I am so sorry, but [`your answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15284146/597657) was right :(

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Don't worry about it :)